# The 'XXX' property on 'XXX' could not be set to a 'null' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.DateTime'

Tags: entity-framework

I am writing a select query in lambda expression in which one of the column name (`ResolveDate`) is null, and I am getting the following error:

```
The 'ResolveDate' property on 'Ticket' could not be set to a 'null' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.DateTime'.
```

How can I set this column nullable? I mean that if column is null in my query result it should not give error?

Comment: Check this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx

Comment: Please show the definition of `ResolveDate`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DateTime is a reference type. You need to use Nullable DateTime in your class.

```
DateTime? ResolveDate = null;
```

or

```
Nullable<DateTime> ResolveDate ;
```

Comment: This is my class, how can I fit your code in my class. Please see the last column of this class, thanks  public class Ticket
    {

        public class Ticket
        {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Screenshot { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime ResolveDate { get; set; }
        
    }

Comment: change `public DateTime ResolveDate { get; set; }` to `public DateTime? ResolveDate { get; set; }`